# apt update gets errors with unexpected hash size and mirror sync in progress?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, mirrors

When I run `sudo apt update`  or `sudo apt-get update` I get this error:

```
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1395 kB]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
  File has unexpected size (13186 != 1394768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:1394768 [weak]
   - SHA256:37cb57f1554cbfa71c5a29ee9ffee18a9a8c1782bb0568e0874b7ff4ce8f9c11
   - SHA1:370c66437d49460dbc16be011209c4de9977212d [weak]
   - MD5Sum:f27cee24646e541717959598ca71230b [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en [510 kB]
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main Translation-en
  
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [30.3 kB]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [266 kB]
Err:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages 
  File has unexpected size (13208 != 266188). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:266188 [weak]
   - SHA256:8ee18cf39af74d093bf34ce50a0b13877c0cee6f130bbf281dc4784f6a008daa
   - SHA1:cc9a5a0bc331e04af3e658231cd3cfe2a63bad86 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:7dc3e94dd3a6573da4d77d160a62f962 [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 15:40:18 +0000
Get:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [129 kB]
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages
  
Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted Translation-en [18.6 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [488 B]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [14.1 MB]
Ign:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en [63.5 kB]
Err:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main Translation-en
  
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en [5652 kB]
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe Translation-en         
  
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [3924 B]
Err:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [286 kB]
Err:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata   
  
Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [217 kB]
Err:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages
  
Get:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [243 kB]
Err:18 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages
  
Get:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse Translation-en [112 kB]
Err:19 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse Translation-en       
  
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [502 kB]
Err:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages  
  File has unexpected size (13202 != 502312). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:502312 [weak]
   - SHA256:602e062de597f2d2b9e24f402025250c72569b017da0117fbff3b7cb9a233a38
   - SHA1:eb51d051bff185a83f3b53cd2244829018a43258 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:2570c8027eeb36853717071949d40abf [weak]
  Release file created at: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 15:40:27 +0000
Get:21 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main Translation-en [119 kB]
Get:22 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [7056 B]
Get:23 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [276 kB]
Get:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted Translation-en [37.3 kB]
Err:24 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted Translation-en
  
Get:25 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted Translation-en [42.5 kB]
Get:26 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [524 B]
Get:27 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [210 kB]
Get:28 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe Translation-en [69.8 kB]
Get:29 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4404 B]
Get:30 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7000 B]
Get:31 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse Translation-en [2264 B]
Get:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [524 B]
Err:32 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Get:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [107 kB]
Err:33 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
  
Get:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en [36.9 kB]                                                     
Err:34 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe Translation-en                                                               
  
Get:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2408 B]                                                
Err:35 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
  
Get:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4192 B]
Err:36 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
  
Get:37 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse Translation-en [900 B]
Fetched 1253 kB in 19s (64.6 kB/s)                      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/37cb57f1554cbfa71c5a29ee9ffee18a9a8c1782bb0568e0874b7ff4ce8f9c11  File has unexpected size (13186 != 1394768). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:1394768 [weak]
    - SHA256:37cb57f1554cbfa71c5a29ee9ffee18a9a8c1782bb0568e0874b7ff4ce8f9c11
    - SHA1:370c66437d49460dbc16be011209c4de9977212d [weak]
    - MD5Sum:f27cee24646e541717959598ca71230b [weak]
   Release file created at: Thu, 21 Apr 2022 17:16:08 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/ab9c07d8c6e91dfc517c822e30ac5c6975cfbfcf7451aade1e26601cd5e99fcd  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/62fde3e2b9f92face05fcdf4009dbda0e13b9d1d0b3f8ba775ef0696d67699f7  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/92102b5d9dfb7804293891528d5e57c3d05949df71af613d4f99fcb7d6a3f488  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/69c65ea370877691c8ac9827e89c68d134055f5c6eb569d963c9cac99e94edb8  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/universe/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/a3c6178f79c431561841218e5fdbdccfbeb8bf00b47dbb305f023a1b73bfa254  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/e24bf9b5daf5387aa5311f69367b248b1d46d37d72480760f91f5a312c7eb43c  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/multiverse/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/38cbbf5467682ada956d14168e301a383d96aaa2f1f694cbaa47cee38b47847d  
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/602e062de597f2d2b9e24f402025250c72569b017da0117fbff3b7cb9a233a38  File has unexpected size (13202 != 502312). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:502312 [weak]
    - SHA256:602e062de597f2d2b9e24f402025250c72569b017da0117fbff3b7cb9a233a38
    - SHA1:eb51d051bff185a83f3b53cd2244829018a43258 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:2570c8027eeb36853717071949d40abf [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 15:40:27 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/8ee18cf39af74d093bf34ce50a0b13877c0cee6f130bbf281dc4784f6a008daa  File has unexpected size (13208 != 266188). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
   Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:266188 [weak]
    - SHA256:8ee18cf39af74d093bf34ce50a0b13877c0cee6f130bbf281dc4784f6a008daa
    - SHA1:cc9a5a0bc331e04af3e658231cd3cfe2a63bad86 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:7dc3e94dd3a6573da4d77d160a62f962 [weak]
   Release file created at: Fri, 12 Aug 2022 15:40:18 +0000
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/c1375ef49ad3efeda9239620cf23e917b0714e663812b756a5bdd13ca5a14eb5  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/main/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/7d87344321e7ff2072b1f6a36844183dd61c2a3263d4ae9d48d23e990107cb42  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/f0db5f2640a86fff65533ff434ba729ad0b80e1e6d352125bb93389bc2674cad  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/eb41395803f2a5ada8867f384150d76fdfb0f1d5bbb2672ab89fb374c67c0a56  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/restricted/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/779d5aba5aee8f67789ea7a84152e3b19573804baff07b1ef23ad894209cc0f5  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/4eb7a154af598a8d572675a2f74e339d5e5c19f91c74b6cabe61da0a6f4f3339  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/i18n/by-hash/SHA256/37bb502ab61fceb883abe051128edc907365c424d3798e3773a986545a4dc4c5  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/universe/cnf/by-hash/SHA256/4f7b8e7b4351c67474726056bab52d51182459a9c02d4af4287af533b7105902  
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-security/multiverse/binary-amd64/by-hash/SHA256/4bf94bf86dd39d82bb03e2fcaa0de1d728409131f80fda05a5f5850e95f9d205  
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

My Distro is Jammy and it runs inside of a Virtual Box VM.
My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is the default that shipped with the destroy, here is what i looks like:

```
## Note, this file is written by cloud-init on first boot of an instance
## modifications made here will not survive a re-bundle.
## if you wish to make changes you can:
## a.) add 'apt_preserve_sources_list: true' to /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg
##     or do the same in user-data
## b.) add sources in /etc/apt/sources.list.d
## c.) make changes to template file /etc/cloud/templates/sources.list.tmpl

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security multiverse
```

How can I get `apt update` to work again?

Comment: Mirror sync is in progress. Wait a bit and try again.

Comment: This issue has been going on for a few days though. Also I'm very new to Linux, what exactly is a mirror sync?

Comment: update Issue is still occuring